# ¿ Por que la variable de instancia toma el valor de la variable de clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo pruebas y me he encontrado este comportamiento que me parece curioso, y es que la variable de instancia self.id toma el valor de la variable de clase id cuando en un principio no son la misma variable, que se puede aprecia bien en este pequeño fragmento de código.

```
class otra_clase:
  id = 3 # Variable de clase
  def __init__(self):
    self.id += 5 # Variable de instancia
    print("La variable de instancia vale:",self.id)
    print("Pero la variable de clase sigue valiendo:",otra_clase.id)
```

self.id +=5 debería causar error ya que no existe, pero lo que sucede es que pasa a valer 8 mientras que id sigue valiendo 3 como se demuestra en el segundo print.
¿Alguien sabe el motivo de este comportamiento?. No encuentro gran información al respecto. Solo una pequeña nota en la documentación de python que dice que cuando coincide una variable de clase con una de instancia la búsqueda da prioridad a la de instancia, lo que me hace pensar es que en este caso se mostraría primero la variable de instancia, no que la variable de instancia tome el valor de la variable de clase. [Enlace a documentación de Python Ver punto 9.4](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)
Gracias.

Comment: la variable `id` existe en toda la clase, si haces`print(self.id)` verás que es `3`. El `self` solo indica que el atributo es específico de una instancia

Comment: Ya pero en principio self.id y id no son lo mismo, ya que como demuestra ese pequeño código al momento de imprimir self.id su valor es 8 mientras que al imprimir id su valor sigue siendo 3

Comment: ambos hacen referencia al mismo objeto, solo que con `self.id` modificas el valor de la instancia pero no de la clase.

Comment: Gracias Christian, eso ya me convence mas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El *problema* aquí es mas bien algo que tiene que ver en como se manejan las variables (o atributos) en una clase. La variable `id` existe dentro de la clase `otra_clase` y es compartida por cualquier intsnacia. La palabra `self` se usa para hacer referencia a una instancia de una clase y sus métodos y atributos son propios de esa instancia y claramente no son compartidos por las demás instancias.

Si nosotros hacemos `otra_clase.id` obviamente veremos el valor `3` de igual forma podemos cambiar su valor `otra_clase.id += 2`. En el *constructor* (inicializador) de tu clase estas creando una variable llamada `id` específica para una instancia (`self.id`), pero python busca en los atributos de la clase para saber si ya existe una variable con ese nombre y al existir ya una variable con el nombre `id` python usa ese valor para asignar el nuevo valor a tu atributo de instancia.

Algo *curioso* es que si hacemos:

```py
class otra_clase:
    id = 3 # Variable de clase
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"id:{self.id}")
```

Se imprimirá el valor `3` esto por lo que había dicho, primero se busca la definición de la variable en la clase, si existe se toma su valor. Esto se puede confirmar si hacemos:

```py
class otra_clase:
    id = 3 # Variable de clase
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"id:{self.valor}") #no existe esa variable en la clase

a = otra_clase()
```

Nos dará el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-27bced46d37d> in <module>()
----> 1 a = otra_clase()

<ipython-input-32-4ab3b797ec8f> in __init__(self)
      2     id = 3 # Variable de clase
      3     def __init__(self):
----> 4         print(f"id:{self.valor}")

AttributeError: 'otra_clase' object has no attribute 'valor'
```

Donde claramente dice `'otra_clase' object has no attribute 'valor'` lo que significa que la clase `otra_clase` no tiene un atributo `valor`.

Por último para aclarar lo que decias:

> [...] una pequeña nota en la documentación de python que dice que cuando coincide una variable de clase con una de instancia la búsqueda da prioridad a la de instancia [...]

Esto quiere decir que si existe una variable de instancia con el mismo nombre que una de clase se te mostrará la de instancia, tal vez lo tengas más claro con el siguiente ejemplo.

```py
class otra_clase:
    id = 3 # Variable de clase
    gato = True
    def __init__(self):
        self.id += 5 # Variable de instancia

a = otra_clase()

print("----accediendo a atributos de clase")
print(otra_clase.id)
print(a.id) #devuelve el atributo de instancia y no de clase
print(a.gato)
```

**Resultado**

```
----accediendo a atributos de clase
3
8
True
```

Como puedes ver, al tratar de acceder al atributo `id` de la clase `otra_clase` mediante la instancia `a` nos devuelve el valor de la instancia y no de la clase, por que se ha priorizado la instancia, a diferencia del atributo `gato` que solo existe en la clase y no en la instancia.